# Jetlang PoolFiber sample

Tags: java, concurrency

I started with [jetlang](http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/) and the basic samples are pretty clear.
What I didn't found is a good sample for using the PoolFiber. Anybody played around
with that already? I read also the retlang samples but it seems little bit different there.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Okami

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a PoolFiber and ThreadFiber are nearly the same. The only difference is that the thread pool needs to initialized and used for creating each PoolFiber.

```
// create java thread pool.
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
//initialize factory with backing pool
PoolFiberFactory fiberFactory = new PoolFiberFactory(pool);
Fiber fiber = fiberFactory.create();
fiber.start();
//use fiber for normal publishing and subscribing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is on Github.

https://github.com/jetlang/jetlang/blob/readme/src/test/java/org/jetlang/examples/BasicExamples.java

Here's the mvn site
http://jetlang.github.io/jetlang/

Comment: github url is broken

Answer (score 0):

### A better pool than Cache is, in involve number of CPU core related to JVM:

```
int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
int threadPoolSize = availableProcessors*2;
ThreadPoolExecutor POOL = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize,
    threadPoolSize, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,  
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
PoolFiberFactory fiberFactory = new PoolFiberFactory(POOL);
```

---